# create table and set auto increment value in hbm file without alter the table

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I need to create a table with id starts from 1001 like below

```
+-----+----------+-----------+---------+
| ID  | LastName | FirstName | Address |
+-----+----------+-----------+---------+
| 1001| CCC     | NULL     | NULL      |
+-----+----------+-----------+---------+
```

How to specify the autoincrement start range in hibernate hbm xml file.

```
  <class name="com.inc.dao.user" table="user" >
            <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
                <generator class="identity" />
            </id> 
.......... 
</class>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to first fire query `ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000;`
before saving data into database and use following code in hbm file:-

```
<hibernate-mapping>
     <class name="com.ora.hibernate.examples.Employee" table="EMPLOYEE">
          <id name="eid" type="int">
              <column name="EID" />
              <generator class="increment" />
          </id>
          <property name="firstName" type="java.lang.String">
          <column name="FIRSTNAME" />
      </property>
     </class>
```

Comment: thank you smita but I need to create id starts from 1001 not from 1.